# Visual Studio Debugging Symbols Package

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have packaged and published a symbols nuget packages for an internal class library within our VSTS environment.  When I install the nuget package the bin folder gets the dll and pdb files.

When I try to step into the code it asks for the location of the source code file.  If I do not specify the location I review Source Search information.  It looks to be looking for the source code in the path specified with the VSTS Builder.

I know you can specify the symbols location with Tools -> Options -> Debugging area.  However, I have multiple projects so would I have to define the symbols location for each project?

Is there a way to have it reference to the package folder by default?